# Failing string compare in Lua

Tags: string, lua, string-comparison

I am trying to put together a small extension for LuCI, the web interface used by OpenWrt. However, the question is very generic and has more to do with lua than anything else.

I have the following code:

```
for k, v in ipairs(nixio.getifaddrs()) do
    if v.family == "packet" then
        s = s .. ifname .. "=" .. v.name .. '?'
        if iface == v.name then
            s = s .. "T\t"
            match = 1
            break
        else
            s = s .. "F\t"
        end
    end
end
```

Every time I run(`ifname="lo"` but it fails with any), the `s` string is printed as follows:

```
lo=lo?F lo=eth0?F   lo=eth1?F   lo=br-lan?F lo=wlan1?F  lo=wlan0?F
```

I've done some debug on it but I still fail to see why the string comparison isn't working in this case. I am not expert on lua, so it may be the case I'm missing something obvious. Could anyone see what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    s = s .. ifname .. "=" .. v.name .. '?'
    if iface == v.name then
```

You are using `iface` in the comparison, not `ifname`. If a variable isn't given a value before, its value is `nil`, but no error is given as it's legal Lua.

Comment: Bit embarrassing to admit but I've been looking at this bit for a while without success. Many thanks for point out the silly mistake :)